# Deleting XML Nodes/Elements with a certain substring through SQL statements

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to delete a list of XML nodes in my XML document with a certain substring, through SQL.

For eg: Delete all XML nodes where name has 'Year1'.

Eg of XML document:

```
<Assets>
        <CarYear1>Honda</CarYear1>
        <BoatYear1>ABC<BoatYear1>
        <CarYear2>TYT</CarYear2>
        <PlaneYear1>LLL</PlaneYear1>
</Assets>
```

So this query should delete all these nodes, i.e.

```
<CarYear1><BoatYear1><PlaneYear1>
```

How do I go about accomplishing this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently found the solution:

```
SET @XML.modify('delete //*[contains(local-name(.),"Year1")]');
```

where @XML is a variable which contains the XML.